# How to discover OpenID IDP, then authenticate with OpenID Provider in PHP

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

I've been looking at implementing OpenID authentication to one of my websites and want to find the best possible solution to make it as easy as possible for users to sign up / in.

Through my long searches on Google I found a few sites that have already covered this in quite a bit of detail; [Usability Research on Federated Login](http://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/UXFedLogin) written by Google, so feel that they are pretty trustworthy design patterns for a best use scenario.

Now in coming to implement this I have found very little PHP support for logins that are done in this manner; the user only has to type in an email address and all of the OpenID details are found automagically. It should also be compatible with Google Apps addresses.

Google provided a link to a great example of this in action http://www.puffypoodles.com/lso2 but although its source code is available to download, it's written in Java, which I'm far from familiar with!

So I was wondering if anyone had found a good PHP implementation that functioned in this manner. php-openid seems too bloated, lightopenid looks great, but doesn't support this functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to point out that LightOpenID now comes with an example provider script you might use as a base.